# Dynamic values are not supported as attributes in annotation- AspectJ Android [AOP Android]

Tags: android, aop, aspectj

I am using custom annotation to log the id which user clicked. But I am getting a error "**Attribute value must be a constant**". My code snippet is below.

```
mAssetId= Asset.getContentId();

  @TrackEvent("track_event")
    @ArrayParams({@Params(key = "content_id",value = mAssetId)})
    protected void attributeMethod() {
    }
```

Thanks in advance. Is there any way to pass dynamic values in annotation rather than static variables or constants. I am using **AspectJ** library for android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to specify runtime values in annotation attributes, only constants, and even the set of possible types is limited to a few types:

> primitives, String, Class, enums, annotations, and arrays of the preceding types

according to the [Java 5 Language Guide - Annotations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/annotations.html).

Answer (score 0):

yes that's right,  I found a solution for logging run time values using annotation.Also i made slight change in anootation to support this

```
 @TrackEvent("track_event")
    protected void attributeMethod(@Params("id") String value) {
    }
```

In my case it worked, hope anyone can help this.

Answer (score 0):

In aspectj native syntax you may catch any runtime variables you need:

```
pointcut rtVar(int id): set(* int SomeClass.mAssetId) && args(id) && within(SomeClass);
```

And then proceed this id variable into joinpoint.

Comment: Any example program for this ?